# Sending data packets over UDP with Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a Script that sends a Magic Packet for the Wake On Lan with Google App Script. So I need to encapsulate a byte buffer into an UDP packet, and then send it to my IP - my PC's redirect port.
Is there a Google App Script library or a way to workaround the problem? The search in the reference didn't returns any results.
Thank You for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Impossible for many reasons. 1) script runs server side so it cant access your ip. 2) only http protocol is supported. 3) client side code from htmlService cant use udp.

Comment: Ok i understood. I know my ip, it is static. Anyway you are telling me that there are no libraries that support udp protocol. Ok i think i will send a http post to my arduino web server that will fire the UDP frame on local LAN. Or better, i will use chrome libraries. Thank you for your help! =)

Comment: but why are you doing this with apps script? why not just a regular client-side JS?

Comment: Oh, only for testing some of the features of Google App Script. I like to play with Google's stuff! =) Also Chrome has a lot of libraries. With [chrome.socket](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket) is possible to send UDP packets, I will try to create a Chrome app using that library! =)